# CS5001: exe does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point

Tags: c#

```
using System;

public class Newton_Ralphson
{
    public double compute(double x,int n,double[] P)            // x, degree, coefficients 
    {
        double pol = 0;
        for (int i = 0;i < n;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < n - i; j++)
                x *= x;
                pol += P[n - i] * x;
        }
        pol += P[0];
        return pol;
    }

public double[] secondary_Pol(int n, double[] P)            //slope
{
    double[] secP = new double[n - 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) 
        secP[i] = P[i + 1];
    return secP;
}

public double Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Estimate the solution for a nth degree polynomial!!! ");
    int n = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the degree of the polynomials! ");
    n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    double[] coefficients = new double[n+1];

    for(int i = 0;i < n+1;i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the coefficients ");
        Console.Write("coefficients of x to the power of {0}: ", n - i);         //decending coefficients 
        coefficients[n-i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
    }


    Console.WriteLine("Initial value is: ");
    double xint = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

    Console.WriteLine("How many times does the function go through? ");
    int precision = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    double polyValue = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < precision; j++)
    {
        polyValue = compute(xint, n, coefficients);                              //y0 in y = slope(x-x0) + y0
        double slope = compute(xint, n - 1, secondary_Pol(n, coefficients));
        xint = (-polyValue / slope) + xint;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(xint);
    Console.ReadLine();
    return 0;
}
```

}

When I add 'static' into the line: public static double Main()
there is another error showed up

error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Newton_Ralphson.compute(double, int, double[])'

error occurred when the two other function executed

Comment: I think, `Main` must be `void`. Also, check the properties of your project and uncheck `enable application framework`

Comment: @T.S. - No, `Main` can return `int` or `void`.  See this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) link, for example.

Comment: 1) *add* `static` to Main 2) fix *those* errors (search on SO for what causes them and how to fix them) 3) go back and fix the next error about Main - always, try to take a step forward. You'll eventually get to the end.

Answer (score 5):

Please see [C# entry point function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954439/c-sharp-entry-point-function)

**C# application, Main() must be the entry point.**

> The reason is because that's what the designers of the language
>   decided to be what to look for as an entry point for your program.
>   They could just as well have used a totally different approach to find
>   the entry point, e.g. using meta data, or instantiating an object for
>   you (Which would require a parameterless constructor). Another reason
>   for naming it void main() is that it's intuitive for users coming from
>   other languages.

Use:

```
public class Newton_Ralphson
{
    public static double compute(double x, int n, double[] P) // x, degree, coefficients 
    {
        double pol = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < n - i; j++)
                x *= x;
            pol += P[n - i]*x;
        }
        pol += P[0];
        return pol;
    }

    public static double[] secondary_Pol(int n, double[] P) //slope
    {
        double[] secP = new double[n - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
            secP[i] = P[i + 1];
        return secP;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Estimate the solution for a nth degree polynomial!!! ");
        int n = 0;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the degree of the polynomials! ");
        n = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        double[] coefficients = new double[n + 1];

        for (int i = 0; i < n + 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the coefficients ");
            Console.Write("coefficients of x to the power of {0}: ", n - i); //decending coefficients 
            coefficients[n - i] = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        }


        Console.WriteLine("Initial value is: ");
        double xint = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        Console.WriteLine("How many times does the function go through? ");
        int precision = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        double polyValue = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < precision; j++)
        {
            polyValue = compute(xint, n, coefficients); //y0 in y = slope(x-x0) + y0
            double slope = compute(xint, n - 1, secondary_Pol(n, coefficients));
            xint = (-polyValue/slope) + xint;
        }
        Console.WriteLine(xint);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
```

1-Change `public double Main()` to   `public static void Main()`

2-change `public double[] secondary_Pol(int n, double[] P)` to  `public static double[] secondary_Pol(int n, double[] P)`

3-Change   `public double compute(double x,int n,double[] P`)    to  `public static double compute(double x, int n, double[] P)`

Comment: +1 for a correct answer and extra-mile points about making the `secondary_Pol` and `compute` methods `static` - i.e. mitigating the next problem that will predictably arise! :)

Answer (score 3):

Add static to all methods. You cannot call a non static method from the static method, without providing object reference. As an alternative you can create an instance of a class and invoke the method:

```
var c = new Newton_Ralphson();
c.compute();
```

Comment: +1 for mitigating the next problem that would arise after fixing `Main`'s declaration - i.e. noting that the other methods need to be declared `static` too.  Still, returning `double` from `Main` is a problem.  Basically, if you and I combined answers, we would arive at @ShahroozJefri's. :}

Answer (score 2):

Creating a new C# console app in Visual Studio will show you what you generally need:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args) // static with a void (or int) return type
        {
        }
    }
}
```

`Main` must be declared `static`.

`double Main` is definitely a problem.  See an older MSDN article on [what a C# main method needs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228506%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) - specifically a `void` or `int` return type.

`Main`'s `string[]` param for args is optional - i.e. can be omitted.  See the aforementioned MSDN article for confirmation.

Finally, adding `public` to `Main`'s declaration is fine but unnecessary and typically skipped.