# What is the entry point of .net executable?

Tags: c#, .net, reverse-engineering

I just disassembled it, I don't know if it's WPF or winforms, I just know there are about 10 namespaces and few hundred classes. How do I find the entrypoint of the exe?

Found it, it is Main() indeed...

Comment: You could ask the author.

Comment: Such answers I usually find by studying the movements in a Brownian Motion producer - say a nice hot cup of tea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every console or windows application normally uses the `Main()` method to execute. This has to be static and looks like this:

```
public static void Main() {
    // your code
}
```

You can provide arguments.

The documentation states that

> There can only be one entry point in a C# program. If you have more than one class that has a Main method, you must compile your program with the /main compiler option to specify which Main method to use as the entry point.

The mentioned parameter allows to specify the type containing the `Main` method. Still it has to be the `Main`. So it is necessary you name it like this.

See this question: [C# entry point function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954439/c-sharp-entry-point-function) for more information on the `Main()` and [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx) for additional information.