# How to change a c# console application's entry point?

Tags: c#, .net, clr, cil, csc

I am wondering whether it is possible to change a .NET console application entry point from `Main` to `Main2` method in the example below:

```
class Program
{ 
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main");
    }

    //desired entry point
    static void Main2(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main2");
    }
}
```

I investigated an IL code of those two. Here is `Main` method:

```
  .method private hidebysig static void 
    Main(
      string[] args
    ) cil managed 
  {
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8

    // other instructions

  } // end of method Program::Main
```

And the `Main2` method:

```
.method private hidebysig static void 
    Main2(
      string[] args
    ) cil managed 
  {
    .maxstack 8

    //other instructions
  } // end of method Program::Main2
```

The only difference is precense of the `.entrypoint` instruction in the `Main` method, which is - as far as I understand - detected by CLR when application is started.

Is there any way to influence `csc` to mark other method with this instruction? Can other compilers do the trick?

**EDIT**
My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954439/c-sharp-entry-point-function), because I am asking about `csc`  compiler (and other complilers) behavior... specifically how to put the `.entrypoint` instruction in the other place

Comment: @Caramiriel yes, this can be done even with visual studio. My question is more about a possibility to mark a method with different signature as an entry point

Comment: Could you give more context to this? Are you trying to do this without having to postprocess the generated code? What's the *purpose* of using `Main2` instead of `Main`? At the moment this feels like an XY problem.

Comment: Alright, I think you should be able to, but not with the csc compiler. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vijaysk/2006/11/30/a-tryst-with-msil/ Ilasm.exe is what you'll need, but I doubt it is any more practical than just adding a new class with a main method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# entry point function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954439/c-sharp-entry-point-function)

Comment: The comment by Caramiriel that you responded to seems to have been deleted, so I apologize if I'm asking the same question, but: are you asking out of curiosity, or is there a practical reason? Because there are other ways to do it within the language - depending on what you are trying to do, you could call Main2 from Main, or use preprocessor symbols (conditional compilation), or use the -main option mentioned in Richard's answer, or even do it at runtime by calling a different method from Main based on a parameter.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović I don't have a practical interest as of now, just curious

Comment: @Caramiriel I'll check this, thx

Comment: The entrypoint is just a `Token for the MethodDef or File of the entry point for the image` in the CLI-Header, see ECMA-335 II.25.3.3. As you already have found, the ilasm compiler lets you define the entrypoint using the `.entrypoint` directive. II.15.4.1.2 tells you what constraints are present for entrypoints.

Comment: @Artem Could you also answer JonSkeet's question? It's highly unlikely that you really need this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved by using `AssemblyBuilder` and other stuff from the `System.Reflection` library.

```
AssemblyBuilder assemblyBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"),AssemblyBuilderAccess.Save);
TypeBuilder typeBuilder = assemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicModule("Module","Test.exe",false).DefineType("Program",TypeAttributes.Public);
MethodBuilder methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("Main2",MethodAttributes.Public|MethodAttributes.Static);
ILGenerator ilGenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
ilGenerator.EmitWriteLine("Main2");
ilGenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
assemblyBuilder.SetEntryPoint(methodBuilder);
typeBuilder.CreateType();
assemblyBuilder.Save("Test.exe");
```

This produces the following `IL` code (`.entryPoint` is placed on `Main2` method):

```
.method public static 
void Main2 () cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 11 (0xb)
    .maxstack 1
    .entrypoint

    IL_0000: ldstr "Main2"
    IL_0005: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(string)
    IL_000a: ret
} // end of method Program::Main2
```

If you execute `Test.exe` you'll see that the `Main2` method is executed

Comment: Sure, but you asked specifically about doing it with `csc.exe`. In this code sample you are using `AssemblyBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible, by definition `Main` is the entry point of a C# application.

> The Main method is the entry point of a C# application. (Libraries and services do not require a Main method as an entry point.) When the
>   application is started, the Main method is the first method that is
>   invoked.

Source: [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/index)

Answer (score 2):

The entry point *must* be named `Main`, as specified by the C# language specification §3.1:

> #### 3.1 Application Startup
>
> ***Application startup*** occurs when the execution environment calls a designated method, which is referred to as the application's entry
>   point. This entry point method is always named `Main`, and can have
>   one of the following signatures:
>
> ```
> static void Main() {...}
> static void Main(string[] args) {...}
> static int Main() {...}
> static int Main(string[] args) {...}
> ```

See the words "is always named `Main`"? If you changed your entry point to something other than `Main` by writing another compiler, that compiler wouldn't be a C# compiler by definition. :)

Comment: also `static async Task Main(string[] args)` ;)

Comment: @TheGeneral I wonder why that signature isn't on the spec... The spec I am quoting here is the 5.0 one. `async` definitely exists back then.

Comment: i think it was C# 7.x that supported it, and i don't think the official specs are available for it yet

Answer (score 1):

The method does have to be called `Main`, but you can use the [`-main`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/main-compiler-option) option to designate which class's `Main` method is the entry point.

(The use of `Main` as the entry point is part of the definition of C# – in the C# v5 specification it is in §3.1, you might be able to overcome this but you would be on your own.)